# How do I sync an RSA fingerprint between two operating systems on the same computer?

Tags: linux, macos, mac, ssh, sshd

My computer is set up to dualboot with Mac OS X and Linux. I have SSH access set up so that I can access it remotely on both OSes. The problem is that whenever I switch from OS X to Linux or vice versa, I cannot SSH in anymore because my SSH client has a different key cached. I can of course just delete ~/.ssh/known_hosts, but this is not an optimal solution. Is there some way I can make the SSHd on both operating systems share the same RSA fingerprint so my client recognizes them as the same computer?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the host's fingerprints are in `/etc/ssh` (files named `ssh_host_*`). They are auto-generated upon package installation. I don't know where they lie in MacOSX, but I think that copying one set of keys over the other OS should do what you want. Be careful to adjust permissions and ownerships according to the original ones (for example, on Linux, private keys have 600 whereas public keys have 644, and all belong to root).

Comment: On OS X, I found the files in /etc. Any idea which files in particular need to be copied, or should I just copy all of them?

Comment: Like I said, all the files starting with `ssh_host_`.

Comment: That didn't work. After rebooting to OS X I get this message from my SSH client: https://cdn.coltondrg.com/blog/2015/03/IMG_20150314_132915.jpg

Comment: Did you flush `~/.ssh/known_hosts` ?

Comment: Before connecting on Linux, yes.

Comment: Just to be clear ; your SSH **server** is dual boot ? And you copied the keys from one OS to the other on the **server** ? Did you flush `~/.ssh/known_hosts` **after** copying the keys ?

Comment: Yes and yes. It seems that OS X has rejected something about the copied keys because now there are more files there than there were before and some of them have different names.

Comment: Could you list the contents of OSX's `/etc/ssh` ?

Comment: The files aren't in /etc/ssh, they are just in /etc. I am going to try copying them again as it occurs to me that I may have forgotten to change the perms.

Comment: Just checked. The permissions are correct, and nothing has changed. I also thought that some new files had appeared, but I was wrong. OS X didn't actually change anything. Here are the listings of both directories: https://cdn.coltondrg.com/blog/2015/03/ssh.txt

Comment: Well, I'm no MacOSX specialist, so I'm at a loss here.